# Inserting a striped line onto an Excel chart through COM Interop

Tags: c#, excel

How can we add a striped line to an Excel chart using C#?

[image]

I am able to create the chart using c# but I didn't get any clue how to add a striped line.
Please make some suggestions.

Thanks

Comment: Please post some code so we can advise

Comment: So far I didn't try to add through com object. Because I didn't found any clue. As suggested below by leoinfo that we need create a series with a fixed vale (average) then change the chart type as line then this should work logically. I will try and if found any difficulties then will let you know. Anyway thanks.

Comment: Are you using Chart control to create this chart ?

Comment: Yes, MS Chart. But I want export same chart into Excel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
- add a data series with a steady value ( of 50 in your case )
- move the new data series to the secondary Y axis
- synchronize the maximum for both Y axes
- set Chart Type for the new data series to Line
- set the Line Style for the new data series to a dash type
```

I know this is not C#, but it is C# as much as you question is :)

When I have things like this, what I'm usually doing is I "manually" do all I have to do in Excel recording a macro with all the stuff. Then I just analyze the macro. You will find a lot of useful information there.

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you so much for your suggestion. It's seem it should work. I will try and let you know here.

Comment: I used the following code and it's working fine:'var seriesCollection = (SeriesCollection) xlChart.SeriesCollection();'
'var series = seriesCollection.NewSeries();'
'series.Values = averageList.ToArray() ;'
'series.ChartType = XlChartType.xlLine;'